# Kiwi Spec Unit Test: Instance method '-attachToVerifier:verifier:' not found

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, tdd, bdd

I'm building some Kiwi tests and getting a warning that I cannot explain. I'm new to Kiwi.

I have a mock object setup:

```
id conversationMock = [KWMock mockForProtocol:@protocol(Conversation)];
[conversationMock stub:@selector(end)];
```

And in my controller, a property called "conversation":

```
@interface MyController ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<Conversation> conversation;
@end
```

The mock is assigned to the property, then in the spec I check for whether the method "end" is called on the conversation:

```
it(@"should end conversation", ^{
  [[[myController.conversation] should] receive] end];
  [myController stopTalking];
});
```

The compiler (LLVM 3.0) is showing a warning: **"Instance method '-attachToVerifier:verifier:' not found"**

What is the cause of this? Is this something I need to fix? (test runs ok, checks the method call to end works ok)

Answer (score 12):

Typecasting the id to a NSObject gets rid of the warning:

[[(NSObject*)[myController.conversation] should] receive] end];

Comment: Have the same problem, and this fixed the problem. However is there no other way to solve it? It kind of destroys the easy-to-read advantage Kiwi have over other testing frameworks.

Comment: I still like Kiwi, and I've been using it a lot in the last 6 months and only run into this issue occasionally. Don't let this one get you down.

Comment: I found this happened when trying to verify on objects of type `id<SomeProtocol>`, except it actually caused an error and wouldn't compile. Casting to `NSObject *` did the trick but is ugly.

Answer (score 9):

What you need to do is:

```
build settings -> Other Linker flags
```

Add the flag: `-all_load`

Comment: I would like to upvote this response but could you explain why this is needed?

Comment: -attachToVerifier:verifier: is defined in a category on NSObject in file NSObject+KiwiVerifierAdditions  
  
- (id)attachToVerifier:(id<KWVerifying>)aVerifier;  
  
<br/>
-attachToVerifier:verifier: is visible at compile time so the application compiles ok. The warning of LLVM is due to the casting id <-> NSObject  
  
As far as I know, The Objective-C linker does not load objects that contain only categories.  
-all_load forces the linker to load all existing object files so eventually it will load the object file that has attachToVerifier…
  
Hope this helps.

Comment: First try `-ObjC`, which only forces loading from object files with Objective-C code. This flag didn't use to work, and `-all_load` was the workaround (see Apple TN QA1490), but it seems to work fine now. (I had the OP's error and this answer twigged my memory; I tried `-ObjC` and it fixed the problem.)

Comment: In the testing or the app target?

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Komposr's answer, I looked at a couple of my projects with Kiwi and found that I needed to do the following:

> Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags

add the flag:    -ObjC

**Note** that I am ***NOT USING*** CocoaPods.  I have downloaded and compiled Kiwi as a static library that I am including...